# why CFRunLoopRun does not work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cfrunloop

```
[self request]; //main thread

- (void)request {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(regFun) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)regFun {
    CFRunLoopRun();
    CCLOG(@"CFRunLoopRun not work");
}
```

Given the previous code, do you know why `CFRunLoopRun()` is not working?. I need to call `regFun` in background.

Are there any other ways to stop background thread?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Most probably there’s an easier way around.

Comment: Check [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001441-CH201-F17704).

Answer (score 1):

It can work.

```
[self request]; //main thread

- (void)request {
    //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(regFun) withObject:nil];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(regFun) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)regFun {
    CFRunLoopRun();
    CCLOG(@"CFRunLoopRun not work");
}
```

But I'm not sure this is the right approach, and I don't know what happened. :(

Answer (score 1):

OK, since you are not telling us what you really need to do, let’s guess. If you just want to run a selector in the background, try Grand Central Dispatch:

```
- (void) request {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [self regFun];
    });
}

- (void) regFun {
    // Running in background, with a run loop available
    // and an autorelease pool, too. After the code finishes:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Will be called on the main thread.
        [self reportBackgroundTaskFinished];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`regFun` is in a background thread, so the call to `CFRunLoopRun()` creates and runs a run loop in this thread. Only there's nothing attached to the run loop, so it exits immediately.

Comment: I do not understand. 

If I do this. CFRunLoopRun() can work.

[self performSelector:@selector(regFun)];

But I need to call regFun in background. Because I hope that main thread continue running.

Comment: what do you mean there's nothing attached to the run loop? Shouldn't it run even though there are no pending operations? e.g. waiting for new operations?

Comment: @paiego no, that's not how it works. The run loop will exit if there's nothing attached to it. You can attach a timer to it and it will remain running indefinitely. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000321-CHDEBABE